# checkBox1.Checked throwing an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

New to C# and visual studio. When testing this line:

```
string myString = (checkBox1.Checked) ? "It's checked" : "Not checked";
```

I get the following error.

> Error 1   The event
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.Checked' can only
>   appear on the left hand side of += or -=

This is when playing with a WPF application. I was following a video tutorial and in their demo it worked perfectly. They might have been using windows forms.

Edit:

```
string myString = (checkBox1.isChecked) ? "It's checked" : "Not checked";
```

throws this error

Error   1   'System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox' does not contain a definition for 'isChecked' and no extension method 'isChecked' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

or this error

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You need a capital I for `IsChecked`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked.aspx) is an event. You need to use the [`IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) property like this...

```
string myString = checkBox1.IsChecked ? "It's checked" : "Not checked";
```

Comment: isChecked threw a different error. I'm mobile right now, but I'll post it when I have the chance.

Comment: Looks like it was a combination of a visual studio bug and not typecasting it as a non-nullable bool.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ToggleButton.IsChecked : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=VS.95).aspx

ToggleButton.Checked is an event, not a boolean: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked(v=vs.95).aspx